# Execute linux command in java and display output to html table

Tags: java, output, html-table, display, linux-disk-free

I have jsp code `df -h` for display disk information on the website.
How  can I show the output to html with table?
Below the code:

```
String[] disk;
String line;
String process;
Process p;
BufferedReader input;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df -h");
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    input.readLine();
    disk = input.readLine().split("\\s+");
<%      
<tr bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
        <td colspan="2">
            <b>Disk</b>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <b>Size<b>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <b>Used<b>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <b>Avail<b>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <b>Use%<b>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <b>Mount<b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
%>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><% out.println(disk[0]); %></td>
        <td align="center"><% out.println(disk[1]); %></td>
        <td align="center"><% out.println(disk[2]); %></td>
        <td align="center"><% out.println(disk[3]); %></td>
        <td align="center"><% out.println(disk[4]); %></td>
        <td align="center"><% out.println(disk[5]); %></td>
        </tr>
<%
        }
    input.close(); 
%>
```

when on linux I execute "**df -h**" it showing like below:

```
[root@svr1 apache-tomcat-7.0.32]# df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_svr1-root   29G  5.3G   23G  19% /
devtmpfs                      1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         1.9G   17M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                         1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                     497M  163M  334M  33% /boot
tmpfs                         380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/0
[root@svr1 apache-tomcat-7.0.32]#
```

But at html I got like below:

[image: Output]

How I can fix it, or what code that I need to change?

Comment: Consider how many times the line ` disk = input.readLine().split("\\s+");` will be executed in your code.

Comment: @yole it should be once, when the script execute it will show all disk information from df -h

Comment: @IHarrisMarfel No. Think again.

Comment: `readLine().split()` reads one line of text and splits it. How many lines does `df` output?

Comment: @yole at my case it show 7 lines, but it will different on every machine.

Comment: The important thing is that it shows more than one line. If you have code that outputs multiple lines and you only execute a statement that parses a single line once, will you get correct results?

Comment: @yole yes i can get correct result, but the code will be to long, and it must static. since not all server use same amount  harddrive or device, it will need to dynamic thing, so if any server execute df -h, the application can get the result

Comment: Sorry, I give up in trying to help you figure out the problem yourself. See my answer below.

Comment: @yole thank you, it's ok, but i still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Try running your code in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this line inside the `while` loop:

```
disk = input.readLine().split("\\s+");
```