# java remove first line from exec command output

Tags: java, linux, output, html-table, display

Relate from my first question at [Execute linux command in java and display output to html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632121/execute-linux-command-in-java-and-display-output-to-html-table)
I have manage to get it work,
but I still have one other question:
how I can remove the first line from the output?
Below is the code:

```
<%
String[] disk;
String line;
String process;
Process p;
BufferedReader input;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df -h");
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
%>
        <tr bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
            <td>
                <b>Disk</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Size</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Used</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Avail</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Use %</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Mounted</b>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
<%
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
    disk = line.split("\\s+");
%>
        <tr>
        <td><% out.println(disk[0]); %></td>
        <td><% out.println(disk[1]); %></td>
        <td><% out.println(disk[2]); %></td>
        <td><% out.println(disk[3]); %></td>
        <td><% out.println(disk[4]); %></td>
        <td><% out.println(disk[5]); %></td>
        </tr>
<%
    }
    input.close();
%>
```

The output is like:

[image: Here]

What I want to remove is `Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted` that showing after table header.

Answer (score 2):

Read 1 line before the `while` loop, by adding this line before the loop:

```
input.readLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

Skip the first line?

```
 int count = 0;
 while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
      count++;
      if (count == 1) continue; 

    disk = line.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: This be sloppy.

Comment: Thank you, work like a charm. same like first answer.